# Opposite of taphold event - jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to trigger something when the user holds a button and trigger something else when he releases it.

On non-mobile, it's straight forward using `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, but on mobile (iOS webview) they don't work.

So I tried to use the `taphold` of jQuery mobile which works, but I want to know what is the equivalent of `mouseup`?

Comment: Have you tried `vmouseup` and `vmousedown` ?

Comment: @Lotus91 is correct, this should be an answer

Comment: Yes looks like it works. Thanks @Lotus91

Comment: You are welcome @kuhaku. Glad to help :)